# iBeacon: didRangeBeacons not called

Tags: frameworks, ibeacon

I have a framework which has all the logic for beacon ranging and monitoring. I have a sample app which has my framework as dependency. I do not get didRangeBeacons or any other callback.

If I move the source files with beacon monitoring and ranging logic from framework to app, app gets the callback.

Why is it that app doesn't get callback only when logic is inside framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have successfully built multiple frameworks that do beacon monitoring and ranging, so **there is no reason this can't work**.  It's hard to say what's wrong without seeing the code but there are a few possibilities that always go along with getting detection working:

1. Make sure your app has been granted location permission by the user.
2. Make sure the CLLocationManager is constructed with a proper delegate, and that it is not being garbage collected.
3. Use breakpoints or log lines to figure out what is going on along the way.  Make sure `startRangingBeacons` `inRegion` and `startMonitoringForRegion` are called with a correct `CLBeaconRegion` definition.

Comment: Can you please help for this question as well? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39913085/beacon-detection-in-background-from-framework