# Beacon detection in background from framework

Tags: ios, background, frameworks, ibeacon, detection

I have a framework which had all beacon detection logic and a sample app which sets up and tears down framework. I want to get region enter and exit notifications after app is killed. I am able to get notifications from app when logic is in app. But when the logic is in framework I don't get notifications. What am I doing wrong?

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

extension AppDelegate: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func registerForBeaconNotifications() {
        let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        let region = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: UUID(uuidString: "83f9daec-4cae-54f1-b64e-846f12345d05")!, major: 10, minor: 10, identifier: "iPhone 6 Beacon")

        locationManager.delegate = self
        region.notifyOnEntry = true
        region.notifyOnExit = true
        region.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = true

        locationManager.startMonitoring(for: region)
        locationManager.startRangingBeacons(in: region)

        // Register for showing notification alerts
        UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(types: .alert, categories: nil))
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didDetermineState state: CLRegionState, for region: CLRegion) {
        let notification = UILocalNotification()

        switch state {
        case .inside:
            notification.alertBody = "Entered region"
            UIApplication.shared.presentLocalNotificationNow(notification)

        case .outside:
            notification.alertBody = "Exited region"
            UIApplication.shared.presentLocalNotificationNow(notification)

        default:
            notification.alertBody = "Region unknown"
            UIApplication.shared.presentLocalNotificationNow(notification)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are many, many things that could go wrong.  Without seeing the code, any answer would be no more than wild speculation.  Can you please post the code?

Comment: I'm not sure if `AppDelegate+BeaconMonitoring.swift` is supposed to be a link to a file, but it didn't come through.  Regardless, the standard practice on StackOverflow is to post a small *excerpt* of your code, showing the parts of the code relevant to your question.

Comment: I was in the middle of update, the last comment was by mistake. I have edited my question with code.

Answer (score 1):

In order to prevent garbage collection which will stop monitoring, `locationManager` needs to be a class variable, and the initialization must take place inside a method.  Like this:

```
let locationManager: CLLocationManager!

func registerForBeaconNotifications() {
    self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    ...
```

Comment: I tried this, no luck :( Anything else that you can think of is wrong?

Comment: Reason why it was not working in I used Swipe up to kill app and in that case app will not be woken up on detecting iBeacons. Is there any solution to handle this?